# Why must MutableMap.keys returns a MutableSet?

Tags: kotlin, collections

The `MutableMap.keys` property is defined as : `abstract val keys: MutableSet<K>`

I understand that the content of `keys` will change as the underlying map will change, but how can the `keys` it-self be modifiable ? IE : I see no logic in calling `map.keys.add(xxx)`

Rq: I came into this problem while creating a proxy around a MutableMap. I have to temper the `entries` and `keys` content, but do not want to implement the `remove/add/clear` methods

Comment: Given the keys can change when the underlying map changes, what do you think would be a better choice?

Comment: I think it's just a quirk of how Kotlin is mapping platform types, for example in Java there is no difference between mutable/immutable so it defaults to mutable one.

Comment: @mattfreake, the standard Kotlin collection interfaces do not enforce immutability. It just means that the caller cannot modify the collection. But the underlying collection can change. It seems to me the MutableMap.keys should be a Set not a MutableSet, even if content can change (if the underlying MutableMap is changed)

Comment: @Pawel indeed, they are the same Jvm class, but for the Kotlin compiler they are different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MutableSet` returned by `keys` throws `UnsupportedOperationException` if you try to add something. It provides remove and filtering (`retainAll`) operations, which can simplify actions that don't need to consider the values, only the keys.

If you're already using a MutableMap, it makes sense that you should also be able to work with the keys directly in a mutable way.

Comment: It makes sens. The returned Set, is partially modifiable, and should therefore be a MutableSet, throwing UnsupportedOperationException for illegal operations.

Answer (score 1):

It corresponds to the Java [`Map#keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) method which is documented as follows:

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, **and vice-versa**. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. **The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations.** It does not support the add or addAll operations.

The bolded parts explain why it's represented as `MutableSet` in Kotlin; otherwise you couldn't port Java code using these capabilities.